# Android Java - have button change tab

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, button, tabs

I recently started coding and have been following tutorials. I'm trying to learn how to use a tab activity right now and followed a tutorial to do it by swiping pages. Here's what I've come up with

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager pager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
}

public void onClickBtn1(View v) {
    //when clicked, take to Main2Activity.java
}

public void onClickBtn2(View v) {
    //when clicked, take to Main3Activity.java

}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch(pos) {

            case 0: return Main2Activity.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
            case 1: return Main3Activity.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");
            case 2: return Main4Activity.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
            default: return Main4Activity.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Default");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
}
```

Can someone please explain to me what's going on in the MyPageAdapter class please?

Also, is it possible that instead of swiping pages that I use a button? For instance, onClickBtn1 will take me to Main2Activity and onClickBtn2 will take me to Main3Activity. I'd like to continue using the tabs instead of creating a new intent.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `what's going on` it is your code, and you are the one, who wrote it and who has to know what you wrote, and what is going on. Also why your `Fragments` are called as Activities?

Comment: Why dont you try and follow this link: 
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Answer (score 0):

Your MyPageAdapter will have as many childs as of your tabs.
For example if you select 1st tab ie position will be 0.
Now in below code new instance of fragment is created for pos 0(First Fragment).

public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch(pos) {

```
        case 0: return Main2Activity.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
        case 1: return Main3Activity.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");
        case 2: return Main4Activity.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
        default: return Main4Activity.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Default");
    }
}
```

---

Switching the tabs on button click is not a cool idea as per user experience.You are using view pager which will help swiping the tabs easily.Execute the code & you will get to know more about the functionality of the code.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use tabs, you could use 4 fragments in an activity and manage them with ViewPager, by this you can go from one to another by clicking on the tabs and swipe left and right

```
    private void initPager() {
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mAdapter.addFragment(firstFragment.newInstance(), getString(R.string.first_fragment_Title));
    mAdapter.addFragment(secondFragment.newInstance(), getString(R.string.second_fragment_title));
    pager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    TextView firstFragmentTabTitle = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, null);
    firstFragmentTabTitle.setText(mAdapter.getPageTitle(0).toString());
    TextView secondFragmentTabTitle = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, null);
    secondFragmentTabTitle.setText(mAdapter.getPageTitle(1).toString());

    tabs.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(firstFragmentTabTitle);
    tabs.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(secondFragmentTabTitle);
    pager.setCurrentItem(mAdapter.getCount());
}
```

and the main activity XML add view pager and tab layout like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".fragments.BankCounterFragment">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:contentInsetEnd="16dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```